ITerm2 - Profile for opening the terminal window at a specific screen location?
I'm using the latest ITerm2 under MacOS 11.17.10.
I'd like to create an ITerm2 profile that will cause the terminal window to always open at a specific screen location. I know how to set the number of rows and columns of the created terminal window within any ITerm2 profile, but I can't find any way to control the coordinates of where on the screen the ITerm2 terminal window will be opened.
I assumed that I could accomplish this by getting Automator involved. However, I'm wondering if there's a simple way within ITerm2's profile capabilities to do this since I’m. It able to get Automator to help.
I tried using AppleScript to launch an appropriately sized iTerm2 window and then move it to a given screen location.
However, when doing so, AppleScript gives an error saying "Can't move class posn of window".
It seems like the windows created by iTerm2 are unable to be moved via any software, and they can only be moved via human mouse interaction.
Is there any way to do this?
